# Atomic move mail message between folders by javax mail

Tags: java, email

If I move a message by copy and delete, the risk is that delete fails (i.e. loose server connection) and I get a duplicate message

how would you do?

Comment: maybe you should move the file

Answer (score 1):

I assume the copy and delete will all be done on the same server together for one request.  In that case, it doesn't matter if the connection is broken between the client and and server after the copy has been done as the server will complete it's task.